# footer at middle of page

Tags: css, position, footer

I searched a lot before asking but didn't find a solution. I tried position attributes, float, eccetera.
I made a site in wordpress and I must have changed something last day in the css I can't remember. The result is the footer does not flow at the bottom with the content.
My (temporary) solution is to have set the #mainwrapper height to 3800px. This pushes the footer down in the homepage but it's still stuck in the middle on other pages.
I'd like the footer to stay right down every content of the site.
Can you help?
Url is www.corcianonline.it, you can notice well the issue here: http://www.corcianonline.it/raccolta-differenziata

Best regards,
Lorenzo

Comment: I played with min-height attribute on #mainwrapper but it is not a definitive solution. It's good on pages with lots of content but on little posts the footer keeps staying very very down.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position to "`fixed`":

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helmet, Freesans, sans-serif;    
}
```

Fixed means, that the `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right`-attributes are relative to the browser-window, not to a parent-Element. 
This way it doesn't matter if you scroll, the footer always stays at the same place.

Comment: Thank you Maja, but "fixed" makes the footer stay on the bottom always. I didn't explain well: I'd need it at the bottom of content and to scroll with the content. I think I found the solution, even if not so rigorous.